# Export procedural textures and animations

Tags: node-editor, texture-baking, unity, procedural

I followed this tutorial to make procedural water which I expect to export and use it in Unity.
Besides material system node it has an animation.
In Unity or is displayed as a blue plane without any noise/bump information. Animation is also not available from Unity
https://youtu.be/MtlSIRh5r_E
What am I doing wrong and is there any way to export procedural textures?
By the way, I tried to bake material nodes to image texture but it was also baked as a solid colour image
I'll be very grateful for the answer.

Comment: Baking is the answer - Blender's node graphs (shader systems) are not compatible with Unity's, so exported (bitmap) image textures are the way to go. I'm not sure why you're getting a solid color when you bake, but that's where I'd place my focus. My guess is that because procedural textures don't need UV maps to function in blender, you haven't UV unwrapped your model(s) yet. Make sure your models are appropriately unwrapped before baking.

Comment: What about animation? Will that gonna work in this approach considering the fact or l it's made of on the procedural basis?

Comment: Will the textures in your animation be in flux (changing constantly)? In that case, you may be better off to build the shader from scratch using Unity's shader graph.

Comment: Well,  water simulation is made with nodes and during the animation I change its xyz to make a waving simulation. I'm not sure if it's in the flux?